# Android - MediaPlayer not playing SHOUTcast stream URL on Android 9 device

Tags: android, url, streaming, android-mediaplayer, shoutcast

Strange issue, I have got an Android 6.0 Huawei and a 9.0 Samsung device, I'm testing the following code on both of them:

```
String streamURL = radioObj.getString(RADIOSTATIONS_STREAM_URL) + "/stream"; 
        Log.i(TAG, "STREAM URL: " + streamURL);
        // prints: http://109.123.70.138:8136/stream

        // Play selected station
        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            playPauseButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_icon);
        }

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(streamURL);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }});

        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();
            simpleAlert("Thers's something wrong with this stream's URL:" + e.getMessage(), ctx);
        }
```

I know that the URL is valid because I'm calling another function that checks for **Artist** and **Current Song**, and it works fine by printing that info in the Logcat, but no music at all from my Android 9 device, Samsung A40. Volume is all up.
Instead, on my 6.0 device, the music plays!
I'm also trying to get some Logcat message like this:

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i(TAG, "MEDIA PLAYER: " + mp.getDuration());
    mediaPlayer.start();
}});
```

But nothing gets printed, it's like if my code ignores the `onPreparedListener` call.
I've also tried to assign my mediaPlayer to mp, like this:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i(TAG, "MEDIA PLAYER: " + mp.getDuration());
    mediaPlayer = mp;
    mp.start();
```

}});

Again, no success at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

I've created a `network_security_config.xml` file in the **res/xml** folder, and placed this code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then I've updated my `Manifest.xml`:

```
<application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="n">
```

Lastly, I've updated my Java code:

```
// Initialize mediaPlayer
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes( new AudioAttributes.Builder()
              .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
              .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
              .build());

try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ctx, Uri.parse(streamURL));
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
            }});
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) { e.printStackTrace();
            simpleAlert(e.getMessage(), ctx);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) { e.printStackTrace();
            simpleAlert(e.getMessage(), ctx);
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();
            simpleAlert(e.getMessage(), ctx);
        }
```